# how to add a variable in a href statement in asp.net using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am creating a navigation menu and one option from the menu calls a changepassword.aspx. I want to pass a variable (userid) for this pane so that when changing the password, it will update the correct user. Below is my code from my home.aspx. When I hover over the Change password link, my link does not include the value in the cuuser variable.

```
<ul id="Adminmenu">
    <li><a href="#">Hyperlink 1</a><span class="darrow">&#9660;</span>
        <ul class="sub1">
            <li><a href="#">hyperlink 1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">hyperlink 1.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">hyperlink 1.3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">hyperlink 1.4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">hyperlink 2</a><span class="darrow">&#9660;</span>
        <ul class="sub1">
            <li><a href="#">hyperlink 2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">hyperlink 2.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">hyperlink 2.3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">hyperlink 2.4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">hyperlink 3</a><span class="darrow">&#9660;</span>
        <ul class="sub1">
            <li><a href="#">hyperlink 3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">hyperlink 3.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">hyperlink 3.3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">hyperlink 3.4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">hyperlink 4</a><span class="darrow">&#9660;</span>
        <ul class="sub1">
            <li><a href="#">hyperlink 4.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">hyperlink 4.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">hyperlink 4.3</a><span class="darrow">&#9654;</span> 
                 <ul class="sub2">
                    <li><a href="#">hyperlink 4.3.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">hyperlink 4.3.2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">hyperlink 4.3.3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">hyperlink 4.3.4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">hyperlink 4.4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="pswrdchange.aspx?userid=" + cuuser>Change Password</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">hyperlink 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

My vb.code has a preinit module when loading the page which has the following:

```
Private Sub home_PreInit(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreInit
    cuuser = Request.QueryString.Get("userid")
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: It looks like you need to use an [`<asp:HyperLink>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink(v=vs.110).aspx) and read up on how to use [ASP.NET controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386451.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

This is very wrong approach for several reasons.
1. On `pswrdchange.aspx` page anyone can change `username=John` to `username=Peter`.
2. On your home page query string `username=` most probably doesn't exist.
3. If you want to use your approach change your code like this.

```
<%--HTML--%>
<a runat="server" id="pswrdchange" href="pswrdchange.aspx?userid=<%#cuuser%>">

'VB
Protected ReadOnly Property cuuser() as String
   Get
     Return Request.QueryString("cuuser")
   End Get
End Property
```